# Flexbox align-self is changing the div's height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox setup like this

```
.container {
display: flex;
min-height: 300px !important;
}
.space-between {
justify-content: space-between;
}
.align-end {
align-self: flex-end;
}
.align-center {
    align-self: center;
}

<div class="container space-between">
        <div class="child" style="max-height: 100px"></div>
        <div class="child yellow-div" style="max-height: 50px"></div>
        <div class="child blue-div" style="max-height: 150px"></div>
        <div class="child pink-div"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

The problem is, when I tried setting the align-self to end or center by applying align-end to child#2 and align-center to child#3, it changes the height of the child where it is being applied.
[image]

Any explanation why this is occurring and the possible fix? Thanks

Comment: add working snippet with CSS what you have defined here. Your given code is not generating the exact scenario what you have shown in pic

Comment: heres a link to a gist -- https://gist.github.com/trashvin/edaec01d0b62f6ab193d57cebbd14622

Comment: please post enough code to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless we specify some `align` property it'll be defaulted to `auto` which will stretch the content to fill the flex,

> [`auto` computes to itself on absolutely-positioned elements, and to the computed value of align-items on the parent (minus any legacy keywords) on all other boxes, or start if the box has no parent. Its behavior depends on the layout model, as described for justify-self.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self)

So in your case once you change the `align` property it'll change its height to `auto`(takes the content height) if there is no specific height applied.

Please check the below snippet. I've applied `align-self` to all the children's and then changed the second child's value to `stretch`

```css
.container {
display: flex;
min-height: 300px !important;
}
.space-between {
justify-content: space-between;
}
.child{
 width: 100px; 
 border: 1px dotted red;
 align-self: baseline;
}
.align-end {
align-self: flex-end;
}
.align-center {
    align-self: center;
}
.yellow-div{
  background: yellow;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.yellow-div+div{
  align-self: stretch;
}
.blue-div{
  background: blue;
  align-self: center;
}
.pink-div{
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container space-between">
        <div class="child yellow-div" style="max-height: 50px"></div>
        <div class="child" style="max-height: 100px"></div>
        <div class="child blue-div" style="max-height: 150px"></div>
        <div class="child pink-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your explanation on the auto / stretch helped me understand the issue. I have another approach https://gist.github.com/trashvin/edaec01d0b62f6ab193d57cebbd14622

Answer (score 0):

`align-self` has a default value of `auto` meaning it will get `align-items` of parent flex container which has a default value of `stretch` and since the child#2 has a `max-height:50px`, it can only stretch up to 50px. When you change the `align-self` value to something else, child#2 won't stretch and its `height` probably get its `min-height` or the height of its children.

https://jsfiddle.net/6xwn80k3/ Check this fiddle and see what happens when you change `align-self` of child#2 with no defined height.